# how to detect if seekbar has not been moved and has no values (then send a toast)

Tags: android, android-seekbar, android-toast

How do i detect if a seekbar has not been moved (and hence does not have a value to display).

I want to make a Toast message if the seekbar has not been swiped (not yet displaying numeric values).

The following are my codes

```
 bubbleseekBar.setOnProgressChangedListener(new BubbleSeekBar.OnProgressChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int progress, float progressFloat) {

                progress = progress / 5000;
                progress = progress * 5000;


                rupiah = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf((progress)));


                kursindonesia = (DecimalFormat)
                        DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
                formatRp = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
                formatRp.setCurrencySymbol("Rp.");
                formatRp.setMonetaryDecimalSeparator(',');
                formatRp.setGroupingSeparator('.');
                kursindonesia.setDecimalFormatSymbols(formatRp);

                txtvalue.setText(String.valueOf(kursindonesia.format(rupiah)));

            }

            @Override
            public void getProgressOnActionUp(int progress, float progressFloat) {

            }

            @Override
            public void getProgressOnFinally(int progress, float progressFloat) {

            }


        });
```

i use https://github.com/woxingxiao/BubbleSeekBar

Answer (score 1):

Then use something like this to check if the user has touched the seekbar?

```
    boolean isTouched;

    bubbleSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                if (isTouched) {

                    //User has already touched the seekBar for the first time.
                } else{

                    // User touches seekBar for the first time.
                    isTouched = true;
                    Toast.makeText(activityName.this, "Touched for first time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://github.com/woxingxiao/BubbleSeekBar
I use seekbar bubble from github, for seekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener not available method @Czral

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to wait for n seconds before showing the toast.

what you can do is create a timer, to check if the seekbar has been moved during that period (or if the value is not at 0).

```
bubbleseekBar.postDelayed( ()-> {
         // do your checking to see if seek bar is moved
         if( bubbleseekbar.getProgress()==0){
             doShowToast();
         }
      } ,   DELAY_MILLIS );
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/rl14h0 
my point is, if you haven't shifted the seekbar to eat there is a message in the form of toast @Angel Koh